# Why does it take more time for radix sort to sort when base is lower?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix

I have run my radix sort on following data

```
data1 = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 25) for _ in range(2 ** 15)]
data2 = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 25) for _ in range(2 ** 16)]
bases1 = [2 ** i for i in range(1, 23)]

for radix sort ( data 1 , base 1 )
[0.7196249961853027, 0.379436731338501, 0.2540769577026367] 

for radix sort ( data 2 , base 1 )
[1.549501895904541, 0.8554239273071289, 0.5452699661254883]
```

I have written time for first 3 bases 2,4,8 . Why is second one is taking twice as much time compared even though bases are same for both ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your benchmark code. That said, `data2` is twice the size of `data1` so the observation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trade off between the histogram | indexes fitting in L1 cache and the number of radix sort passes. In my testing, I've found that using base 2^8 = 256 is close enough to ideal for sorting 32 bit or 64 bit pseudo-random unsigned integers, taking 4 passes for 32 bits, 8 passes for 64 bits.